# Laravel 7 <img> tag is not displayed

Tags: php, laravel

**I do a udemy course**

**I have one problem**

**When I start to create a post I have to insert a photo**

**When I add a photo, the photo is not displayed**

**While the "View Source Page" clearly shows that the photo is inserted and should be displayed but not displayed**

**I wrote the code li**

```
<img src="{{ $post->image }}" alt="">
```

**I tried to add this extension as well but it didn't work again**

```
<img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}" alt="">
```

**View Source Page**

```
<img src="posts/2F2K2uHwvdL11pB8FSmecTeKCCNe1qIaLjCTcOPU.jpeg" alt="">
```

**PostController**

```
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {
        $image = $request->image->store('posts');

        Post::create([
            'title'       => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'content'     => $request->content,
            'image'       => $image
        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Post is successfully created');

        return redirect(route('posts.index'));

    }
```

**CreatePostsRequest**

```
class CreatePostsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'       => 'required|unique:posts',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image'       => 'required|image',
            'content'     => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title','description','content','image','published_at'
    ];
}
```

**If anyone can help me for a good part of the night I fight this but I fail**

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Are you uploading the image with the post?

Comment: do you check the image path exist?

Comment: @Hardood Look I added the rest of the code

Comment: @ZeroOne Look I added the rest of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not utilising the full storage path name, as seen in your View Page Source.

First you need to make sure your storage and public folders are linked by using the artisan link command:

`php artisan storage:link`

Next you can specifiy the public directory with your store method:

`$image = $request->image->store('public/posts');`

Now you can access your image with:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/posts/' . $post->image)}}" alt="">
```

Comment: It is also a good practice to always check if the image has stored correctly then Insert a row to the database.